# Jquery: Finding a 1 on a page and appending a class to an existing class in a row

Tags: jquery, html

I have the html below rendered on a page(This is a partialview)

```
<tr class="inv">
  <td class="box">..</td>
  <td class="idate">Jul 01,2013</td>
  <td class="pflag">1</td>
<tr>
```

I will like to append another class to the

```
<tr class="inv">
```

that will make it look like this

```
<tr class="inv past">
```

whenever

```
<td class="pflag">1</td> has a value of 1
```

Here is what I tried below but no luck

```
    $(function() {
        $('tr .inv').each(function(){
          if($(this).find('td.pflag').html() == '1') $(this).addClass('inv past')
        });
    })
```

Comment: Just a syntax error Try `$('tr.inv').each(function()` instead `$('tr .inv').each(function()` remove white space between tr and .inv

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$("td.pflag").filter(function (){return $.trim($(this).text())=="1";}).closest(".inv").addClass("past")`

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there!

```
$(function() {
    $('tr.inv').each(function(){ // no space for tr.inv because .inv is not a child of <tr>
        if($(this).find('td.pflag').text() == '1'){ // use text here to avoid any html chars
            $(this).addClass('past'); // just add past to this tr
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be something with the document not being ready.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr.inv').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('td.pflag').html()=='1'){
            $(this).addClass('past');
            console.log("Added");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('past');
            console.log("Removed");
        }        
    });
});
```

Working in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y6WMY/19/